# Not able to find appsettings.json file in Main Function?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to access `appsettings.json` from Main method and pass to `DBContext` to get connection string. But at `Configuration = builder.Build();` error. Is there any alternative method I can try to get connection string?

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.  
The physical path is 'C:\Trunk\Repos\ZiplinePackage\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json'.'
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        var context = new DataContext(Configuration);
        var speCommonData = context.SpeCommonData.Where(s => s.Status == "NLM GENERATED").ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]

**DataContext.CS** file

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    private string _connectionString;
    public static IConfigurationRoot configuration;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MISCDBConnection"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try marking file as a resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application cannot find the file when it is running. That means the file was not included into the build. Make sure the `appsettings.json` has these properties:

- Build Action = Content
- Copy to Output Directory = Copy if Newer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SetBasePath` method

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();
```

or set base path like this

```cs
string basePath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
```